# Terraform modules forces to define all the blocks defined in resources, is there any way to make dynamic import from resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline, infrastructure-as-code, terraform-modules

I am trying to create aws codepipeline using resources in TF. here is my resources section in m,y TF.

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name     = var.name                                   
  role_arn = var.role_arn                               



 artifact_store {
    location = var.location                             
    type     = var.type
  }



 stage {
    name = var.stage1_name                              



   action {
      name             = var.action1_name     
      category         = var.source_category
      owner            = var.source_owner    
      provider         = var.source_provider            
      version          = var.source_version             
      output_artifacts = var.source_output_artifacts    



     configuration = {
        ConnectionArn        = var.connection_arn           
        FullRepositoryId     = var.full_repository_id         
        BranchName           = var.branch_name   
        OutputArtifactFormat = var.output_artifact_format             
      }
    }
  }



 stage {
    name = var.stage2_name                               



   action {
      name             =  var.action2_name               
      category         =  var.build_category             
      owner            =  var.build_owner                
      provider         = var.build_provider              
      input_artifacts  = var.input_artifacts             
      output_artifacts = var.build_output_artifacts      
      version          = var.build_version     
      
      configuration = {
        ProjectName = var.project_name
        EnvironmentVariables = var.environment_variables /*jsonencode(
        [
          {
            name  = var.environment_name
            type  = var.environment_type
            value = var.environment_value
          }
        ]
       )  */     
       }
    }
  }
}
```

In my TF modules section, creating codepipeline by calling the resources given above. my modules code is

```
module "codepipeline_notification" {
  source = "../../modules/codepipeline"
  name                    = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_name                                   
  role_arn                = aws_iam_role.cp_lambda_deploy_role.arn #var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_role_arn                               
  location                = module.s3_codepipeline_artifact.s3_bucket_account_id   #var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_location                             
  type                    = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_type



 stage1_name             = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_stage1_name    
  action1_name            = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_action1_name            
  source_category         = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_source_category
  source_owner            = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_source_owner   
  source_provider         = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_source_provider            
  source_version          = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_source_version            
  source_output_artifacts = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_source_output_artifacts
  full_repository_id      = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_full_repository_id         
  branch_name             = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_branch_name               
  output_artifact_format  = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_output_artifact_format
  environment_variables   = jsonencode(
        [
          {
            name  = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_environment_name
            type  = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_environment_type
            value = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_environment_value
          }
        ]
       )         
  build_output_artifacts        = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_build_output_artifacts   
  connection_arn          = module.codestarconnections.arn
  stage2_name             = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_stage2_name                               
  action2_name            = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_action2_name     
  build_category         = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_build_category   
  build_owner            = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_build_owner      
  build_provider         = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_build_provider              
  build_version          = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_build_version               
  input_artifacts         = var.codepipeline_lambda_notification_input_artifacts   
  project_name             = module.codebuild_notification.name
}
```

with this approach, I am trying to create 4 pipelines where one pipeline has only 2 stages and other 2 pipeline has 3 stages, If I define 3 stages in resources then Terraform forces the modules to create 3 stages in all pipelines where I need onyl two stages. Is there any way in terraform to define in resources and use the resource in modules based on condition

Comment: "based on condition" - based on what condition? You haven't provide any info on what is your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got an answer to your question, but yes, there is a way.  It's called Dynamic Pipeline.  I have a repository that walks you through the usage of the dynamic pipeline.  In short, you treat the resource like a dynamic resource using each statement and passing in the configuration as a map.

The module looks like this:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  for_each = var.code_pipeline
  name     = "${local.name_prefix}-${var.AppName}"
  role_arn = each.value["code_pipeline_role_arn"]

  tags = {
    Pipeline_Key = each.key
  }

  artifact_store {
    type     = lookup(each.value, "artifact_store", null) == null ? "" : lookup(each.value.artifact_store, "type", "S3")
    location = lookup(each.value, "artifact_store", null) == null ? null : lookup(each.value.artifact_store, "artifact_bucket", null)
  }

  dynamic "stage" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "stages", {})
    iterator = stage
    content {
      name = lookup(stage.value, "name")
      dynamic "action" {
        for_each = lookup(stage.value, "actions", {}) //[stage.key]
        iterator = action
        content {
          name             = action.value["name"]
          category         = action.value["category"]
          owner            = action.value["owner"]
          provider         = action.value["provider"]
          version          = action.value["version"]
          run_order        = action.value["run_order"]
          input_artifacts  = lookup(action.value, "input_artifacts", null)
          output_artifacts = lookup(action.value, "output_artifacts", null)
          configuration    = action.value["configuration"]
          namespace        = lookup(action.value, "namespace", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Executing Module**

```
module "code_pipeline" {
  source = "../module-aws-codepipeline" #using module locally
  #source       = "your-github-repository/aws-codepipeline" #using github repository
  AppName       = "My_new_pipeline"
  code_pipeline = local.code_pipeline

}
```

**Sample locals.tf with pipeline variable**

```
 locals {

  /*
DECLARE enviornment variables.  Note each Action does not require environment variables
*/
  action_second_stage_variables = [
    {
      name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
    },
    {
      name  = "NamespaceVariable"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "some_value"
    },
  ]

  action_third_stage_variables = [
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE_1"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "VALUE1"
    },
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE 2"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "VALUE2"
    },
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE_3"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "VAUE3"
    },
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE_4"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "#{BLD.NamespaceVariable}"
    },
  ]

  /*
BUILD YOUR STAGES
*/

  code_pipeline = {
    codepipeline-configs = {
      code_pipeline_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_name:role/role_name"
      artifact_store = {
        type            = "S3"
        artifact_bucket = "your-aws-bucket-name"
      }
      stages = {
        stage_1 = {
          name = "Download"
          actions = {
            action_1 = {
              run_order        = 1
              category         = "Source"
              name             = "First_Stage"
              owner            = "AWS"
              provider         = "CodeCommit"
              version          = "1"
              output_artifacts = ["download_ouput"]
              configuration = {
                RepositoryName       = "Codecommit_target_repo"
                BranchName           = "main"
                PollForSourceChanges = true
                OutputArtifactFormat = "CODE_ZIP"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage_2 = {
          name = "Build"
          actions = {
            action_1 = {
              run_order        = 2
              category         = "Build"
              name             = "Second_Stage"
              owner            = "AWS"
              provider         = "CodeBuild"
              version          = "1"
              namespace        = "BLD"
              input_artifacts  = ["Download_ouput"]
              output_artifacts = ["build_outputs"]
              configuration = {
                ProjectName          = "codebuild_project_name_for_second_stage"
                EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode(local.action_second_stage_variables)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage_3 = {
          name = "Validation"
          actions = {
            action_1 = {
              run_order        = 1
              name             = "Third_Stage"
              category         = "Build"
              owner            = "AWS"
              provider         = "CodeBuild"
              version          = "1"
              input_artifacts  = ["build_outputs"]
              output_artifacts = ["validation_outputs"]
              configuration = {
                ProjectName          = "codebuild_project_name_for_third_stage"
                EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode(local.action_third_stage_variables)
              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The full use of the module can be found in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cwnit/toolkits/tree/master/collections/terraform/aws/aws-codepipeline/dynamic-pipeline).  In your case, you could pass in multiple resources to create various pipelines in one module with unique and custom stages and actions.  I hope this helps.